# What is the query parameter name embedded in the url on Google Custom Site Search?

Tags: url, google-custom-search

I'm using Google Custom Site Search and I want the initial search box on every page in the navigation, but want the results to appear on a different page (searchresults.html), however its asking me for the query parameter name embedded in the url? What would this be for me? the default q does not work.

I'm a newbie so don't even know what a query parameter is and how i'd go about creating/getting one?

Comment: Query parameters are the variable in an url after the question mark, e.g.: `http://example.com?param=value`

Comment: Sorry that doesn't mean anything to me. The web address is http://urpromotions.co.uk and the search results page is http://urpromotions.co.uk/new/searchresults.html (test page). So what would the query parameter name embedded in the url be for it? Thanks

Comment: At that URL there isn't one. Can you show me the documentation of Google where it states that you need the query param. Maybe I can see what they mean.

Comment: I can not as its under my log in. When you create custom. The new site is in dev. Initial search is on http://urpromotions.co.uk/new and the results need to appear on http://urpromotions.co.uk/new/searchresults.html. When I search on http://urpromotions.co.uk/new nothing happens but if a search on http://urpromotions.co.uk/new/searchresults.html I get results, but that defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: @PeeHaa Never mind its just started working, I was using 'q' as the default query param. (as suggested on a Google forum) changed it to 'query' and is now working fine. Thanks though.

Comment: Post it as an answer for other people if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write "query" instaed of the default "q" in the box.